# Compiling Unity to WebGL gives a Node ESM module error

Tags: unity, node.js, unity-webgl, mirror-networking

I'm trying to build my multiplayer game to WebGL in Unity (using Mirror). However, when I press "build", it gives me the following *three* errors:

```
Building Builds\Web\index.html failed with output:
(node:78892) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///[unity install dir]/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/BuildTools/Preprocess.js:91
  return;
  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:21)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
Building Builds\Web\Build\Web.loader.js failed with output:
(node:80608) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///[unity install dir]/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/BuildTools/Preprocess.js:91
  return;
  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:21)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
Building Builds\Web\TemplateData\style.css failed with output:
(node:83572) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///[unity install dir]/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/BuildTools/Preprocess.js:91
  return;
  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:21)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I've tried Googling it, but I couldn't find anything other than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156607/nodejs-error-of-the-esm-module-loader-is-experimental-after-using-experiment) which didn't really help me at all.

- OS: Windows 11
- Unity version: `2022.3.4f1`
- Node.JS version (I'm not sure if it really matters): `20.8.1`

**EDIT**:
I looked in "Preprocess.js" to see where the error was and it looks like it was here:

```js
if (!locals.outputPath) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(locals.variables)));
  return;
}
```

There's just a return in the global scope... Not sure if this has to do with anything but I thought it might be helpful

**EDIT 2**:
I commented out the return statement:

````js
file:///[unity install dir]/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/BuildTools/Preprocess.js:2
  fs: require("fs"),
      ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///[unity install dir]/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/BuildTools/Preprocess.js:2:7
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:137:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing `"type": "module"` from my home directory's `package.json`. I'm guessing it had something to do with Unity using CommonJS internally and then my NodeJS install not letting it use it because of the `package.json` config.